# Unit test for filter in jersey-spring

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have added one health link to my web service in web.xml as

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>healthChecker</filter-name>
    <filter-class>test.HealthChecker</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>healthChecker</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/health</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>basicAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported><!-- filter supports asynchronous processing -->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>basicAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now I want to unit test this health check

```
@Test
public void testHealthCheck() {
    ClientHttpRequestFactory originalRequestFactory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    try {
        WebTarget target = target().path("/health");;

        final Response mockResponse = target.request().get();

        Assert.assertNotNull("Response must not be null", mockResponse.getEntity());
    } finally {
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(originalRequestFactory);
    }
}
```

Code for health checker is

```
public class HealthChecker implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //do nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        String json ="{\"status\":\"UP\"}";
        response.getWriter().append(json);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filter) throws ServletException {
         // do nothing

    }

}
```

Now when I execute this unit test I am getting 404 error. If I see target then url in target is http://localhost:9998/health, which is right.

I used this url in chrome but couldnot get anything.

This is done in jersey test framework

Comment: why are you using a filter instead of a servlet? i think the 404 might be because there is no servlet mapped to that path.

Comment: where have you define path on your class? Annotation?

Comment: path is fine since this works fine when I actually run application, I can hit http://localhost:8080/health

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use the right approach, a servlet filter is not meant to be used for this purpose, it is used to perform filtering tasks and here as you break the filter chain (you don't call `chain.doFilter(request, response)`), you block the request such that you get a `404` error.

As you obviously use **Jersey**, you should rather create a rest component and test it with the [**Jersey Test Framework**](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

Your rest component that will return the status as a JSON object anytime the path `/health` is requested:

```
@Path("/health")
public class HealthChecker {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response check() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
            .entity("{\"status\":\"UP\"}")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Then we test that we actually get what we expect:

```
public class HealthCheckerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(HealthChecker.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateGroup() {
        Response response = target("/health").request()
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get();
        Assert.assertEquals("{\"status\":\"UP\"}", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this but when I call with /heath its asking for authorization.How can I skip authorization.I have editied my code , please see.

Comment: @Alien01 there is something that you probably miss because AFAIK what I propose in my answer (based on the Jersey Test Framework) doesn't rely anyhow on a `web.xml`.